# How to best determine whether the date format is MM/dd or DD/mm in java

Tags: java, string, date-formatting

I have list of files coming and I need to analyze them using java. The date field is read from files as `String` and I need to parse it in to `LocalDatTime`. The problem is it is now known that whether the first part of date is month or day.

The format in them can be anything but most probably in the following formats.

```
"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm","MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm",
        "MM/dd/yy HH:mm"
```

e.g.

```
9/8/2020 23:50
9/8/2020 23:55
9/9/2020 00:00
```

In the above case date field can be guessed from when the date changes from `9/8/2020 23:50`
`9/9/2020 00:00` . This means the date changed from 8th to 9th and hence the format is `MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm`

```
9/8/2020 23:00
9/8/2020 23:50
10/8/2020 00:00
```

In the above case date field can be guessed from when the date changes from `9/8/2020 23:55`
`10/9/2020 00:00` . This means the date changed from 9th to 10th and hence the format is `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm`

The file can also be `2020-09-08 23:00:00`. The only thing I know is that the date will change in the series while the month will seldom change.

What is the best way to cater this issue.

Comment: So you're saying that in isolation, you don't know whether 10/9/2020 is October 9th or September 10th?

Comment: Are the dates contiguous or can there be gaps?

Comment: @JGNI no gaps in dates .. but the different between hours can be different for each file. e.g. 23:00 then 23:30 in one file while in another it can be 23:00 followed by 23:05 and vice versa

Comment: *FYI:* All your date formats are wrong, since they use `hh` when they should be using `HH`.

Comment: @WSJ Yes this is the issue

Comment: @Andreas thanks for reporting. I was initially trying it via Simpledateformat which uses `hh`

Comment: @AhmedRana [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) or [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html), doesn't matter, since they both have `hh` and `HH` and with same meanings, so your reasoning is way off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the sulution could be just counting of changes of first and second part and compare result. This is not extra efficient, but quite simple:

```
// true - day/month/year
// false - month/day
public static boolean isDayMonthYearFormat(List<String> sortedDates) {
    int firstPartChangeAmount = 0;
    int secondPartChangeAmount = 0;
    int prvOne = -1;
    int prvTwo = -1;
    boolean count = false;

    for (String date : sortedDates) {
        String[] parts = date.split("[\\/\\s+:]");
        int one = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
        int two = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);

        if (count) {
            firstPartChangeAmount += prvOne < one ? 1 : 0;
            secondPartChangeAmount += prvTwo < two ? 1 : 0;
        }

        count = true;
        prvOne = one;
        prvTwo = two;
    }

    if (firstPartChangeAmount == secondPartChangeAmount)
        throw new RuntimeException("can't detect between MM/dd and DD/mm");

    return firstPartChangeAmount > secondPartChangeAmount;
}
```

**Output:**

```
System.out.println(isDayMonthYearFormat(Arrays.asList("9/8/2020 23:50", "9/8/2020 23:55", "9/9/2020 00:00")));  // false
System.out.println(isDayMonthYearFormat(Arrays.asList("9/8/2020 23:00", "9/8/2020 23:50", "10/8/2020 00:00"))); // true
```

Comment: Seems a good approach. But there are other formats as well. e.g. `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm` . I think the solution can be improved by adding checks of first part or second part is > 12 then it definitely is the `dd` part.